Can we plug in any expression into a two-variable continuous map for a discrete topology var? Or must be continuous?
Let $X=(\Bbb{Z}, \delta), \ Y =(\Bbb{Z}, \rho)$ be two topological spaces ($\delta=$ the discrete topology and $\rho =$ the profinite aka Furstenberg topology).   Suppose that we have a continuous function from $X\times Y$ into $Y$ called $f$. I’m wondering  since $X$ has discrete topology whether we can plug anything in for $x$ in the function $g:Y \to Y, \ g(y) = f(x,y)$ ie where $x= h(y)$, or is it necessary that $h$ needs to be continuous from $Y \to X$?  That is to say I need $g$ to be a continuous map as well.

My function f is constructed to be continuous in each var, and it’s proved continuous jointly in the two vars from the product.

Let $f(x,y)=x+y$ and let $h(y)=\begin{cases}-y {\quad \rm if \quad} y\neq0,\\1-y {\quad \rm if \quad} y=0. \end{cases}$
Then $f$ is continuous, but $$g(y)= f(h(y),y)=\begin{cases}0 {\quad \rm if \quad} y\neq0,\\1 {\quad \rm if \quad} y=0, \end{cases}$$ is not continuous.  In particular $g^{-1}(2\mathbb{Z}+1)=\{0\}$, which is not a union of arithmetic progressions, with non-zero common difference.
